# Trouble Loading .txt file using pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to load a .txt file in python using pandas.read_csv(). The data shows Time vs HeatFlow for a calorimeter. I would like load the file so that python reads it as two separate columns.

Here is a sample of the first few lines of the data file.

Time         HeatFlow
0               -4.266626
0.000028        -4.266519
0.000056        -4.266411
0.000083        -4.266316
0.000111        -4.266221
0.000139        -4.266125
0.000167        -4.26603
0.000194        -4.265958
0.000222        -4.265887

I have had some success using excel to convert the .txt files to tab delimited .txts. Unfortunately, some of my data files are too large for excel.

Ideally I would be able to directly load the original .txt file into python.

When running the following code:

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('TestFile.txt')

I get the error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

I have tried using different encodings and delimiters to no avail. I have never encountered this error and do not know how to address it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error typically occurs when the file you're trying to read has a different encoding than `UTF-8`, which is the default encoding used by pandas when reading in files. So if not sure what encoding you got use this example to give you sort of an understanding. If you're unsure about the encoding of the file, you can try using the chardet library to find it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import chardet

with open('TestFile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())  # detect the encoding of the file
    
data = pd.read_csv('TestFile.txt', encoding=result['encoding'])
```